# <meta> in source code but I can't find it in files or plugins

Tags: plugins, admin

I've got someone verified in my Google Search Console for our site and it's using a meta tag in the head.

I've checked header.php in the theme and the child and it's not there.  I've double checked wp_head (includes/general). and it's not there either.

I found some plugins to add scripts to the head but it isn't there.  I checked Google Tag Manager we're not injecting anything there.

Can anyone think of anywhere I haven't looked where this meta tag might be coming from?

I've checked the Google Analytics and Tag Managers plugins the owner has installed and it's neither of them (at least not in the settings)

Comment: did you try searching all site files for some string?  Same with DB?  It has to be somewhere.

Comment: If meta tag is not added in the theme file, then it must be done via some plugin or active theme. There are many plugins that takes meta tag value as input and render it on the front-end. Similarly most themes also offer such option. You may need to check all the plugins or theme options to verify it.

Comment: I think @riddlemethis has a good idea with a DB search which is quite quickl. Then I can do files after that if need be. Of its in a file then I probably need to uninstall a sneaky plugin!

Comment: @JustinWaulters yes it is

Comment: @Eoin Sorry, I didn't understand completely. I thought it was unexpected meta like description or something. Yoast adds a lot of stuff, does it still happen without Yoast actice?

Comment: Good question Incan disable and test

Comment: ok, let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a lot of things, and as RiddleMeThis says, a DB search would shine light on the situation.

However, in my experience, most cases of unexpected meta are generated with Yoast.

For your specific case, here is how to link Google Search Console with Yoast - it might help you remove the unwanted meta:
https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/add-website-google-search-console/

Let me know if it doesn't work, and we can dive into searching the DB!

Comment: Yoast was the correct answer.  In which case I will leave it for now.  Thanks everyone for your answers.